# Read json children nodes with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Need some help on reading json data with d3. here's the json

```
{
  "name": "Main Course",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Chinese",
      "children": [
        {"name": "Noodles"},
        {"name": "Rice"},
        {"name": "Xinjiang Roast"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Indian",
      "children": [
        {"name": "Rice"},
        {"name": "Paratha"},
        {"name": "Dal Fry"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make a list from these data like below,

```
<ul>
<li>Main Course</li>
  <ul>
  <li>Chinese</li>
    <ul>
    <li>Noodles</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Xinjiang Roast</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Indian</li>
    <ul>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Paratha</li>
    <li>Dal Fry</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

This is where I am stuck,

```
d3.select("body")
        .append("ul")
        .selectAll("li")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("li")
        .attr("id","mylist")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
        })

 d3.select("#mylist")
        .append("ul")
        .selectAll("li")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("li")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.children[0].name;
        })
      }
```

It gives me the below result,

```
<ul>
<li id="mylist">Main Course<ul>
<li>Chinese</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I guess the problem I am facing is trying to get the children data/nodes. I tried using index like children[i] but got undefined error. How do I properly loop through all the children and append it to a list nested to their parent nodes?

Comment: You need [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the need to use d3 for this.

Try this:

```
function makeMenu(jsonObj, container) {
    container = container || document.body;

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = jsonObj.name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    container.appendChild(ul);

    if(jsonObj.children) {
        for(var i=0; i<jsonObj.children.length; i++) {
            li = document.createElement('li');
            makeMenu(jsonObj.children[i], li);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}
```

[A working example can be found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/22g22/2/)

Comment: It's a part of a larger visualization in d3. The list will later have other bound data and input controls that will control aspects of the visualization. So, I am preferring d3 to do this.

Comment: While I'm sure there is a way, I'm afraid I don't know d3 well enough to help you then.